# iOS Reminder app like checkboxes

Tags: ios, user-interface, checkbox, ios8, reminders

I would like to use checkboxes in my app because the user should have the ability to check/ mark things as completed. I would like these checkboxes to look like the Reminders app's checkboxes but I do not find something like that in the object library.

Does anyone know how to get the Reminder app like checkboxes?

For example:

[image]

Or something like:

[image]

Comment: Apple doesn't provide controls like check box or radio buttons... Use `UIButton`, with custom images !!

Comment: But I would like the animations (like in inner circle zooming in) as well.

Comment: use 2 images for this action

Comment: Yes but it would only switch between images, nothing fancy.

Comment: This looks useful https://github.com/DavydLiu/DLRadioButton

Answer (score 0):

set `state config` of button in storyboard(attributes section).
select and set Default and selected images.
It is work similar as a checkBox.

Comment: And if I want animations with that? I am just going to write my own checkbox UIControl.